Plotting graph of a function in Python
I want to graph a function of the number of divisors using Numpy. But there is a problem with np.arange.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(t):
    num_of_divisors = 0
    for i in np.arange(1, t+1):
        if t % i == 0: 
            num_of_divisors += 1
    return num_of_divisors

t2 = np.arange(1, 100, 1)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t2, f(t2), color='black')
plt.show()

 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I tried, but it was a ValueError:
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

You have to vectorize your function, add @np.vectorize just before def f(t):

You have to vectorize your function.
Since it is inherently iterative, you cannot replace it easily with pure numpy code. A workaround is to use numpy.vectorize:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

@np.vectorize
def f(t):
    num_of_divisors = 0
    for i in np.arange(1, t+1):
        if t % i == 0: 
            num_of_divisors += 1
    return num_of_divisors

t2 = np.arange(1, 100, 1)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t2, f(t2), color='black')
plt.show()

Output:


@mozway has the right answer, but if you are planning on running this for a large set of numbers and need a bit more of performance, you can get rid of the inner loop with:
@np.vectorize
def f2(t):
    candidates = np.arange(1, t+1)
    num_of_divisors = ((t % candidates) == 0).sum()
    return num_of_divisors

With 1000 elements:
%%timeit 
f(t2)
27.9 ms ± 2.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit 
f2(t2)
2.7 ms ± 16.2 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

np.all(f(t2) == f2(t2))
True

